# Elixir mix file - :applications vs :extra_applications - when to use which?

Tags: elixir

From [Elixir documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Compile.App.html):

> `:applications` - all applications your application depends on at runtime. By default, this list is automatically inferred from your dependencies. Any extra Erlang/Elixir dependency must be specified in `:extra_applications`. Mix and other tools use the application list in order to start your dependencies before starting the application itself.
>
> `:extra_applications` - a list of Erlang/Elixir applications that you want started before your application. For example, Elixir’s `:logger` or Erlang’s `:crypto`.

If the list for `:applications` is automatically inferred, then what are some example scenarios when we should add an application to `:applications` instead of `:extra_applications`? and vice versa?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you use `applications` then no inference is done and `extra_applications` are not considered. When `applications` are not provided, they are set to something like this:

```
applications_inferred_from_deps ++ extra_applications
```

You use one or the other, but never both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you think of any scenario where we may want to use `:applications` instead of `:extra_applications` + `deps`? It seems to me `:applications` is redundant.

Comment: It's an older interface. `extra_applications` an inference was only introduced in Elixir 1.4, the `applications` key exists for compatibility.

Comment: It makes sense now :)

Comment: There is a [great post](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2017/9/22/elixir-applications-vs-extra_applications-guide/) about applications vs extra_applications with examples and details for different use cases.